# Is there a way to look up another column should there be no match in the first one using Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have 2 tables, 1 contains the member data and the other is the transaction table. The members has different member IDs with different information on each IDs, but I only look up the member ID we consider as unique. Now the problem is, in the transactions table, it sometimes records the transaction under the other member's ID. Here's a table to further illustrate the situation:

TABLE = MEMBER_DATA

| MEMBER_ID | LINKED_ID | FNAME | LNAME | MEMBER_TYPE | TIER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8888-1234 | X1234 | JOHN | SMITH | REGULAR | - |
| 7777-3333 | X1234 | JOHN | SMITH | - | GOLD |
| 8888-6666 | X0993 | HANNA | MONTANA | REGULAR | - |
| 7777-9999 | X0993 | HANNA | MONTANA | - | PLATINUM |

TABLE = TXN_TABLE

| MEMBER_ID | TXN_COUNT | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8888-1234 | 1 | 3 |
| 8888-6666 | 2 | 4 |
| 7777-9999 | 2 | 2 |

RESULT:

| MEMBER_TYPE | MEMBER_ID | TXN_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| REGULAR | 8888-1234 | 1 |
| REGULAR | 8888-6666 | 2 |

The member is assigned a MEMBER_ID known to them that starts with 8888, for us, there is another ID assigned to them for their other information that starts with 7777 (it's already that way when I got here so no possibility of change). The way we know they are the same person is because of the LINKED_ID. I only looked at MEMBER_IDs with MEMBER_TYPE = REGULAR to count the members. In the transactions table, it sometimes records the transaction to the member's other ID so I don't get an accurate count of transactions. The solution I came up with is to transform the MEMBER_DATA table to add their other MEMBER_ID and other information.

**The question is, how now do I look up the MEMBER_ID2 if the TXN_TABLE MEMBER_ID doesn't match MEMBER_ID1?**

TRANSFORMED TABLE:

TABLE = TRANSFORMED_MEMBER_DATA

| MEMBER_ID1 | LINKED_ID | FNAME | LNAME | MEMBER_TYPE | TIER | MEMBER_ID2 | TIER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8888-1234 | X1234 | JOHN | SMITH | REGULAR | - | 7777-3333 | GOLD |
| 7777-3333 | X1234 | JOHN | SMITH | - | GOLD | - | - |
| 8888-6666 | X0993 | HANNA | MONTANA | REGULAR | - | 8888-6666 | PLATINUM |
| 7777-9999 | X0993 | HANNA | MONTANA | - | PLATINUM | - | - |

EXPECTED:

| MEMBER_TYPE | MEMBER_ID | TXN_COUNT | TIER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REGULAR | 8888-1234 | 1 | GOLD |
| REGULAR | 8888-6666 | 4 | PLATINUM |

**Note: Relationship of TXN_TABLE and MEMBER_DATA is on column MEMBER_ID**

Comment: Do you need a DAX or M solution?  Are you sure about your tranformed data table? Should 8888-6666 not have a member id of 7777-9999?

Comment: I'm looking at a DAX solution since I would want to be able to create visualizations and look at certain time periods for transactions. I completely forgot that the TXN_TABLE has dates.

Answer (score 3):

For a Power Query solution:

- Join the two tables based on `MEMBER_ID`
- Group by `LINKED_ID`
- Aggregate by `MAX` except for the `TXN_COUNT` which you aggregate by `SUM`
- Remove the LINKED_ID column

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MEMBER_DATA"]}[Content],
    MEMBER_DATA = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"MEMBER_ID", type text}, {"LINKED_ID", type text}, {"FNAME", type text},
        {"LNAME", type text}, {"MEMBER_TYPE", type text}, {"TIER", type text}}),

    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TXN_TABLE"]}[Content],
    TXN_TABLE = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"MEMBER_ID", type text}, 
        {"TXN_COUNT", Int64.Type}, {"AMOUNT", Int64.Type}}),

//Join the tables
    Joined = Table.NestedJoin(MEMBER_DATA,"MEMBER_ID", TXN_TABLE, "MEMBER_ID", "joined", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Joined, "joined", {"TXN_COUNT"}, {"TXN_COUNT"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded joined", {"LINKED_ID"}, {
        {"MEMBER_TYPE", each List.Max([MEMBER_TYPE]), type nullable text}, 

    //This next works because '8888' > '7777'
    //  if your assigned ID's have a different pattern, may need to change this
        {"MEMBER_ID", each List.Max([MEMBER_ID]), type nullable text},
         
        {"TXN_COUNT", each List.Sum([TXN_COUNT]), type nullable number}, 
        {"TIER", each List.Max([TIER]), type nullable text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"LINKED_ID"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

***Results from your data above***
[image]

Comment: is joining TXN and MEMBER_DATA more efficient than keeping them separate and using measures to create visualizations? I forgot that TXN_TABLE also has a date and I should also still be able to look up the dates when the transactions happened.

Comment: @bixby I don't know. It will probably depend on what you mean by "more efficient".  Create a measure and see for yourself. What problem do you see returning the date of the transaction?  What did you try? What were the results? Depending on how it is stored, you can probably do that easily as an additional Table.Group aggregation.

Comment: One happens at query time (measure) and the other happens at refresh time (table join in PQ). Only yourself can be the judge which one is more efficient for your use case. Is the transform in Power Query incurring a massive increase in refresh time? If so, perhaps a measure is better. Is the measure making your report extremely slow? Perhaps implementing something at refresh time is more fit for purpose.